# Selenium automation non html

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

Can we automate non-HTML components using Selenium webdriver? I have tried, but I couldn't. Are there any ways to automate them? Please some one explain me with an example.

Comment: What do you mean with 'automating'? Its rather unclear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Which non-HTML components have you got in mind? Flash? No AFAIK you can't do it with Selenium, use Ranorex instead. Yes it is not free, but is good.